# How to use cleanSession flag, or retain flag with the aws mqtt JS sdk?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, mqtt, publish-subscribe

I am unable to find examples online on how to use cleanSession flag or retain flag in both publish and subscribe for mqtt aws sdk in JS. I know, that the python SDK has cleanSession flag.
Is there such a flag available for the JS sdk? I have scanned through the code repo and I couldn't find any such flag. Could anyone please guide me. This is the code repo:
https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js

I have a publisher publishing messages to topics to the AWS broker and a subscriber subscribed to those topics to receive those messages. If a subscriber joins late, I want the subscriber to get the last message which the publisher had sent to the topics. This is the reason I want to use persistent sessions, for which I believe I have to set the cleanSession flag to false.

Could anyone please give me an example on how to use the flag for the JS sdk?

Comment: I can't seem to find the cleanSession flag in the python SDK.  Can you point me to it?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The AWS-IOT MQTT broker does not support retained messages.

It also only supports QOS 0 and 1 (not 2)

You can see the  restrictions on the AWS-IOT broker [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/mqtt.html)

Comment: Hi, the document says it does support persistent connections now:   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/mqtt-persistent-sessions.html

Comment: But still no support for retained messages, which would give you the last published value.

Comment: It appears that AWS-IoT MQTT does now support retained messages, but the amplify sdk does not implement setting the retained flag.